# How to get Data from table in twig by checking a checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, checkbox, twig

I created a table in twig template. In the first Column you can check a checkbox. After checking checkbox it should remove the row. My problem is how I can get the Data to remove it.

Here is my table

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
      <thead>
          <tr>
                  <th> <label for="checbox">Check</label></th>
                  <th>id</th>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Age</th>  
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          {% for products in user.products %}
          <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkBox"  id="ic" value=true/></td>
              <td >{{ products.id }}</a></td>
              <td >{{ products.name }}</td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}


      </tbody>
  </table>

 if(isset($_POST['checkBox'])== 'true'){

        $products = $_POST['??????'];


        $zl = 0;
        foreach ($products as $pr)
        {
          $em = $this->getDoctrine ()->getManager ();
          $pr = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:Products')->find($pr);
          $user->removeProduct($pr);
          ++$zl;
        }


        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();
```

}

How I can get the Data?  `$products = $_POST['??????'];` I don"t know which parameter I have to put  here to get the Data from the selected checkbox.

Comment: I advise you to do this in Ajax. Try to put your PHP code in a file that you call it with Ajax via Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change checkbox's value from `true` to row's product id and check if `$_POST['checkBox']` is array and it is not empty.

Replace html part

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkBox"  id="ic" value=true/>
```

with

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkBox[]"  id="ic" value="{{ products.id }}" />
```

and php part

```
 if(isset($_POST['checkBox'])== 'true'){

    $products = $_POST['??????'];
```

with

```
 if(isset($_POST['checkBox']) && !empty($_POST['checkBox'])){

    $products = $_POST['checkBox'];
```

Comment: Thank you. Could write an example?

Comment: And of course you have to place the table inside form tag which points to the corresponding action and place a button "delete selected products" to submit it